# Fat polymerization vs hydrolysis and temperature change

Tags: experimental-chemistry, chemical-biology, lipids

I have an experiment on fats that I have to do in a few hours and I am very lost between fat/oil (lipid) polymerization due to high temperatures and hydrolysis. It appears that both result in the breakdown of fats but in very different ways. Our class assistant suggested to do an experiment about different temperatures affect fat breakdown which results in acid creation that affects pH. I would track that ph change at different temperatures with different fats for the experiment. Please help as I am lost if that can even be done with simply a heating system, different fats and oils and pH strips??

Comment: As far as I know, fats and oils do not polymerize. How much do you know about the hydrolysis (under which conditions it happens, what the products are)? If you want to know what experiments you can do with fats, oils, heat and pH strips, that is a very broad question, probably too broad to be appropriate for this site.

Comment: You're only going to get hydrolysis if you have OH- present